# How can I tell Git to ignore insubstantial commits?

Tags: git

I have an Ubuntu cloud server where I pull from a repo on Bitbucket, but have no intention of pushing in the other direction.

When I do a 'git status' on the cloud server I get the following:

```
    On branch master
    Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
      (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

However, the 4 commits mentioned above are not substantive, because I can succesfully pull from Bitbucket.

Is there a way to tell git to forget or ignore those insubstantial commits, so that it stops warning me to publish them?

Comment: "However, the 4 commits mentioned above are not substantive, because I can succesfully pull from Bitbucket." <- this is not exact as it seems that commits from bitbucket do nt seem to be the same;

Comment: is your uestion "how to stop tracking bitbucket now I cloned it"?

Comment: @OznOg I want to continue to pull from Bitbucket as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to continue to pull from Bitbucket as necessary.

Then create your new (4 here) commits on a different branch than `master` (and move master back to `origin/master`)

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b myBranch
git branch -f master origin/master
```

No more warning during a `git status` done on a purely local branch like `myBranch`.

Anytime you want, you can pull from BitBucket:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

If you want your own commit to be based on the latest from master:

```
git checkout myBranch
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove upstream branch tracking by using (from the branch itself)

> git branch --unset-upstream

then when you will want to pull again, you will be able to pull using

> git pull origin/master

Answer (score 0):

For my situation I found the following solved the problem:

```
git rebase
```

Following which:

```
# git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: I maintain it is best to work on a separate branch. master should be used only to track origin/master.